# Searching a string input for a phrase in Python

Tags: python, string-matching

Is there a way in Python to search an input string for a phrase, and then return e.g. a 1 if it is there, or a 0 if not?

I want it to work like this:

```
def findphrase(var):
if re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(var), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search is True:
    return 1
else:
    return 0

def howareyou():
    print("So",name, "how are you today?")
    howis = input("")
    if findphrase('not well')(howis) is 1:
        print("Oh, that's not good. I hope you feel better soon")
    elif findphrase('well')(howis) is 1:
        print("That's good.")
    elif findphrase('not bad')(howis) is 1:
        print("Better than bad, I suppose.")
    elif findphrase('bad')(howis) is 1:
        print("Oh, that's not good. I hope you feel better soon")
    elif findphrase('not good')(howis) is 1:
        print("That's a shame. I hope you feel better soon.")
    elif findphrase('good')(howis) is 1:
        print("That's good.")
    else:
        print("I dont know how to respond to that. Keep in mind I am a work in progress. At some point I may know how to respond.")
```

Comment: Quite possible. Look at the `re` module documentation.

Comment: Or the `in` operator, which tells you whether one string is contained within another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation is buggy and won't work.

1. `.search` is a function, it is an object. Since it is an object, it will never equal to True. Hence you will always return 0.
2. `findphrase('well')(howis)` in the code is invalid syntax, since you don't return a function from `findphrase`
3. `input` in Python2 will evaluate the statement as well, which will throw `NameError`s for string inputs. So use `raw_input` instead.
4. You could easily use `in` operator against using a regex here
5. `if findphrase('good')(howis) is 1:` is an identity test, since you are returning `0`/`1` only, you could check the values directly using `if findphrase('good')(howis):`

---

You could use a simple lambda function here:

```
findphrase = lambda s, var: var.lower() in s.lower()
```

and call it like:

```
>>> findphrase("I'm not well", "Not Well")
True
>>> findphrase("I'm not well", "Good")
False
```

---

If you want to return a function, 
then you could use

```
findphrase = lambda var: lambda original_string: var.lower() in original_string.lower()

>>> howis = raw_input()
I'm doing GooD
>>> findphrase("Good")(howis)
True
```

Comment: Just curious why the choice of a lambda here? I know it's just personal preference, but I rarely use them unless I have a specific reason **to** use them.

Answer (score 1):

A regex is probably overkill for this.  I'd use `in`.

## Example 1:

The way I'd implement `findphrase()`, given your requirement of returning a `1` or `0` is:

```
>>> def findphrase(phrase, to_find):
...   if to_find.lower() in phrase.lower():
...     return 1
...   else:
...     return 0
... 
>>> phrase = "I'm not well today."
>>> to_find = 'not well'
>>> in_phrase = findphrase(phrase, to_find)
>>> assert in_phrase == 1
>>>
```

Note the use of `to_find.lower()` and `phrase.lower()` to ensure that capitalization doesn't matter.

## Example 2:

But frankly, I'm not sure why you want to return 1 or 0.  I'd just return a boolean, which would make this:

```
>>> def findphrase(phrase, to_find):
...   return to_find.lower() in phrase.lower()
... 
>>> phrase = "I'm not well today."
>>> to_find = "not well"
>>> in_phrase = findphrase(phrase, to_find)
>>> assert in_phrase == True
>>>
```

In the event that you truly need to use the results as a `1` or `0` (which you don't if you rewrite your `howareyou()` function), `True` and `False` convert to `1` and `0`, respectively:

```
>>> assert int(True) == 1
>>> assert int(False) == 0
>>>
```

## Additional Notes

In your `howareyou()` function, you've got a number of errors.  You're calling `findphrase()` as `findphrase('not well')(howis)`.  That would only work if you're returning a function from `findphrase()` (a closure), like so:

```
>>> def findphrase(var):
...     def func(howis):
...         return var.lower() in howis.lower()
...     return func
... 
>>> phrase = "I'm not well today."
>>> to_find = "not well"
>>> in_phrase = findphrase(to_find)(phrase)
>>> assert in_phrase == True
>>>
```

This works because a function is just another type of object in Python. It can be returned just like any other object.  Where you might want to use a construct like this is if you're doing something along these lines:

```
>>> def findphrase(var):
...     def func(howis):
...         return var.lower() in howis.lower()
...     return func
...
>>> phrases = ["I'm not well today.",
...            "Not well at all.",
...            "Not well, and you?",]
>>>
>>> not_well = findphrase('not well')
>>>
>>> for phrase in phrases:
...     in_phrase = not_well(phrase)
...     assert in_phrase == True
...
>>>
```

This works because you're assigning the results of `findphrase('not well')` to the variable `not_well`.  This returns a function, which you can then call as `not_well(phrase)`.  When you do this, it compares the variable `phrase` that you're providing to `not_well()` to the variable `var`, which you provided to `findphrase()`, and which is stored as part of the namespace of `not_well()`.

But in this case, what you'd probably really want to do would be to define your `findphrase()` function with two arguments, like one of the first two examples.

You're also using `findphrase(...) is 1`.  What you probably want there is `findphrase(...) == 1` or, even more pythonic, `if findphrase(...):`.